# "Error Did not find value '____' in VLOOKUP evaluation."

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Please see my public spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11RMN7uN_woEQVzlDEkX6vSARTCGYYBjWs11ZDU-6Shc/edit#gid=1276951687

My goal is to get the Location Code from `tab 1` into `tab 2` (`tab 2` is a subset of specific zip codes and I need them with their matching Location Codes alongside them).

I was attempting to use a `VLOOKUP` to do it, but got this error:

```
Error: Did not find value '30096' in VLOOKUP evaluation.
```

In this case, I would expect to see the Location Code `79459` in this cell.

Guess I'm misunderstanding how `VLOOKUP` works and/or how to use it. I tried to follow the prompts.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your sheet. But can be fixed.

- Your "Zip Code" values in column `B` in your sheet `Lookup` are text instead of numbers.
  *Tip: You can use `=ISNUMBER()`to check the value of a cell.*
- You have a lot of data in your `Lookup` sheet
- `VLOOKUP` does not work because (as also mentioned by CodeCamper) it always "looks" from left to right.

---

### Steps to fix the sheet.

**Step 1:**
Change the formula you use in `Lookup!B` to:


```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,"[0-9]+")*1))
```

This way (using `IFERROR`) you avoid the `#N/A` in your empty lines and by using `*1` you change them all to numbers.

**Step 2:**
Move column `Lookup!B` to the beginning of the sheet, thus making it `Lookup!A`.
We do this **because** of the fact that you have a lot of data and use your formula (in sheet `AdamHelp`)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,{VALUE(Lookup!B2:B),VALUE(Lookup!A2:A)},2,FALSE))))
```

the `VLOOKUP` **calculations take forever to complete**.

When using `{VALUE(Lookup!B2:B),VALUE(Lookup!A2:A)}` you do solve the left search issue of the `VLOOKUP` function but at the same time you create unnecessary -*in your case*- arrays that really slow down the sheet.
*Tip: If moving the column to the beginning is not possible, move it after column `C` (`Display name`) and make necessary adjustments to the final formula. **Left `VLOOKUP` is to be avoided by all means when possible**.*

**Step 3:**
Finally, change your formula in `AdamHelp` to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Lookup!A2:B,2,0)))
```

Following these steps you will not only get the correct results but will also see a **huge improvement on the calculation time** of the sheet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I created a new spreadsheet copy for testing: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uahrGZREngB2Z7jMfdOfy9mL2MLQ02qFQ_gK-vEJpgU/edit?usp=sharing

There are some issues - you can see them.

1. Any leading zeros are being stripped from the zip codes.
2. There is an error in the 'Relevant Zip Codes' tab (Error VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range.)

Comment: _"There is an error in the 'Relevant Zip Codes' tab (Error VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range.)"_. You had a mistake in the formula you copied. I fixed it. It works fine now. _""_. Keeping the leading zeros is a completely different thing from what you were asking. In any case you need to choose `Format` > ` Number` > `More Formats` > `Custom number formats` > `00000` > `Apply` if the specific format is not there you have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much an error as a statement of fact. 30096 does not exist in column A which is where you are looking for it. The way vlookup works is the column you are looking for a match is always to the left. The index is the column you want to return when it finds a match.